# ECMAScript 5 - Регулярное выражение для выбора из двух вариантов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярное выражение, которое бы проверяло, что в строке присутствуют либо 2-3 заглавные буквы русского алфавита, либо 3-4 заглавные буквы латинского алфавита?

У меня работает только с двумя отдельными регулярками: `[А-Я]{2,3}` и `[A-Z]{3,4}`.

Comment: Между ними поставьте `|`, если там ни каких символов больше не надо. Либо больше данных по строке представьте в вопросе.

Comment: _2-3 заглавные буквы_ - подряд? или могут быть в разнобой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование пайпа (символа `|`) поможет в выборе.
Будет находить **только указанное** количество повторений, больше или меньше - уже провал.

```js
let log  = document.querySelector('#log'),
    test = document.querySelector('#test');

test.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if(/^(?:[а-яё]{2,3}|[a-z]{4,6})$/i.test(test.value)){
    log.style.color = 'green';
    log.innerHTML = 'Passed!';
  }else{
    log.style.color = 'red';
    log.innerHTML = 'Failed';
  }
});
```

```css
#test:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' autofocus /><br />
<span id='log'></span>
```

Comment: У вас тут `ё` потерялось

Comment: @VenZell, верно, всё время забываю что почему-то `ё` не включено в набор `а-я`. Дискриминация!

Comment: Вот символ | как раз у меня и не работает.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов: Как не работает? Курит, что ли? Покажите Ваш код.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов, как "не работает"? Всё работает, поделитесь Вашим кодом тогда.